# R - Convert points into points in the centre of raster of 30 x 30m

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, raster, rasterizing

I want to transform a specific dataset of spatial points to points in the centre of a raster.
The result sould be spatial points and for each point in the original dataset a point in the centre of the raster.

I made this example code to get a better idea of the task.

```
library(raster)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

setwd("C:/Users/chris/Desktop/Regionaler Klimawandel und Gesundheit/Urban COPD/R/Data/")
getwd()

set.seed(55)

r <- raster(xmn= 800000, 
            xmx= 810000,
            ymn= 7200000,
            ymx= 7210000)
p <- as(r@extent, 'SpatialPolygons')
pts <- spsample(p, n = 100, "random")
pts$value <- runif(100, min=0, max=10)
df <- as.data.frame(pts)

ggplot(data= df, aes(x, y, fill =value))+
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 2)+
  scale_fill_viridis()+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: Example points in a Raster]

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the `values` column to be associated with the grid points at x, y in the `raster` object `r`.

That being the case, you can append the following line to your above code:

```r
r <- rasterize(cbind(df$x, df$y), r, df$value, fun = mean)
```

So now `r` looks like this:

```r
r
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 180, 360, 64800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 27.77778, 55.55556  (x, y)
#> extent     : 8e+05, 810000, 7200000, 7210000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : layer 
#> values     : 0.08473639, 9.896253  (min, max)

plot(r)
```

[image]

Note that you have to look closely to see the points because of the resolution of the raster.

If you lower the resolution of the initial raster, by creating `r` as:

```
r <- raster(xmn= 800000, 
            xmx= 810000,
            ymn= 7200000,
            ymx= 7210000,
            ncols = 50, nrows = 50)
```

Then you can see the points more clearly and note that they match the points on your `ggplot`:

```r
r <- rasterize(cbind(df$x, df$y), r, df$value, fun = mean)

plot(r)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I added to get spatial points `Points <- rasterToPoints(r, fun=function(x){x>0}, spatial = T)`  Thank you very much! Helped me a lot!